# Which key failed in Python KeyError?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I catch a `KeyError`, how can I tell what lookup failed?

```
def poijson2xml(location_node, POI_JSON):
  try:
    man_json = POI_JSON["FastestMan"]
    woman_json = POI_JSON["FastestWoman"]
  except KeyError:
    # How can I tell what key ("FastestMan" or "FastestWoman") caused the error?
    LogErrorMessage ("POIJSON2XML", "Can't find mandatory key in JSON")
```

Comment: Since you would have to branch on the key that failed anyway, it's probably clearer to put each lookup in a separate `try` statement.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Take the current exception (I used it `as e` in this case); then for a `KeyError` the first argument is the key that raised the exception. Therefore we can do:

```
except KeyError as e:  # One would do it as 'KeyError, e:' in Python 2.
    cause = e.args[0]
```

With that, you have the offending key stored in `cause`.

Expanding your sample code, your log might look like this:

```
def poijson2xml(location_node, POI_JSON):
  try:
    man_json = POI_JSON["FastestMan"]
    woman_json = POI_JSON["FastestWoman"]
  except KeyError as e:
    LogErrorMessage ("POIJSON2XML", "Can't find mandatory key '"
    e.args[0]
    "' in JSON")
```

It should be noted that `e.message` works in Python 2 but not Python 3, so it shouldn't be used.

Comment: Thank you.  I don't suppose this is documented anywhere?  I couldn't find it in the Python docs.

Comment: @QuestionC [`BaseException.args`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/exceptions.html#BaseException.args) is documented, but not in enough detail that its uses are obvious.

Comment: Is this advisable to use, since it is undocumented and the arguments might change?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you're using any modules to assist you - if the JSON is coming in as a dict, one can use `dict.get()` towards a useful end.

```
def POIJSON2DOM (location_node, POI_JSON):
    man_JSON = POI_JSON.get("FastestMan", 'No Data for fastest man')
    woman_JSON = POI_JSON.get("FastestWoman", 'No Data  for fastest woman')
    #work with the answers as you see fit
```

`dict.get()` takes two arguments - the first being the `key` you want, the second being the value to return if that key does not exist.

Comment: Sorry this is so late, but I guess you're answering the underlying question rather than the direct query by OP about `KeyError`.

Answer (score -3):

If you import the `sys` module you can get exception info with `sys.exc_info()`

like this:

```
def POIJSON2DOM (location_node, POI_JSON):
  try:
    man_JSON = POI_JSON["FastestMan"]
    woman_JSON = POI_JSON["FastestWoman"]

  except KeyError:

    # you can inspect these variables for error information
    err_type, err_value, err_traceback = sys.exc_info()

    REDI.LogErrorMessage ("POIJSON2DOM", "Can't find mandatory key in JSON")
```

Comment: @Alex Thornton's answer is much simpler, and answers the question more directly. By the way, since this is getting downvoted, is there something wrong fundamentally with my approach? I've used this method and I'd like not to use it if it causes problems. Help me out :)

Comment: I see no reason for the downvote. The syntax for capturing an exception prior to Python 2.6 was less than clear, so explicitly calling `sys.exc_info()` was a reasonable approach.

Comment: Not a downvoter, but: it's more complicated than `except Foo as e`, and it's a race condition in multithreaded code. What if two threads raise a KeyError before either of them can call `sys.exc_info`? Both threads would see the same output, so one of them could be wrong. The `except Foo as e` syntax is an atomic operation.