# Specific Try and Except

Tags: python, input, try-catch, except

```
continue = True
while continue:
     try: 
        userInput = int(input("Please enter an integer: "))
     except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, wrong value.")
     else:
        continue = False
```

For the code above, how would I be able to catch a specific `ValueError`? What I mean by that is if the user inputs a non-integer, I would print out `"Sorry, that is not an integer."`. But if the user input is an empty input, I would print out `"Empty Input."`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the call to `input` outside of the `try:` block and place only the call to `int` inside it.  This will ensure that `userInput` is defined, allowing you to then check its value with an if-statement:

```
keepgoing = True
while keepgoing:
    userInput = input("Please enter an integer: ")  # Get the input.
    try:
        userInput = int(userInput)  # Try to convert it into an integer.
    except ValueError:
        if userInput:  # See if input is non-empty.
            print("Sorry, that is not an integer.")
        else: # If we get here, there was no input.
            print("Empty input")
    else:
        keepgoing = False
```

Comment: I'm surprised that this is the best way to do it, as for something like a `KeyError` you can get what caused it with [`e.args`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23139024/how-do-i-find-out-what-key-failed-in-python-keyerror/23139085#23139085), but that just returns the message for this. Strange.

Comment: You could get the input value out of the message contained in `e.args`, but that would be more involved than my solution.  I purposefully kept the code simple so as to not exceed the OP's experience level.

Comment: I probably would do it in this way regardless as otherwise it would be too long-winded. Still, I'm surprised that the arguments passed to `BaseException` can't be accessed in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this:

```
keepgoing = True
while keepgoing:
     try: 
        userInput = input("Please enter an integer: ")
        if userInput == "":
           print("Empty value")
           raise ValueError
        else:
           userInput = int(userInput)
     except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, wrong value.")
     else:
        keepgoing = False
```

Comment: in your case the empty input would allow the loop to exit.