# How to handle a KeyError(key) from err error?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, keyerror

Some of the ticker symbols are causing the code below to fail.

Is there a way to:

1. Identify which tickers are causing the code to fail (via a log, ECT) so I can remove them?
2. Ignore failing tickers and still write to my db?
3. Use any other workaround to get my data (even partially) into my db?

March 20th code

```
import pandas as pd
from quickfs import QuickFS as qf
import os
import json
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from contextlib import suppress
import sys
import logging

# load th key 
api_key = '783afaac81792374538967ad9ef72226f07be115'
client = qf(api_key)


#Technology_Software_Infrastructure
tickers = ['ATEN:US','BB:US','BKI:US','BOX:US','CCCS:US','CINT:US','DAVA:US','DOCN:US','ETWO:US','EVTC:US','FLT:US','FORG:US','FOUR:US','GDDY:US','INFA:US','IOT:US','MFGP:US','MSP:US','NET:US','NEWR:US','ORCL:US','PAGS:US','PATH:US','PING:US','PLAN:US','PLTR:US','RAMP:US','S:US','SAIL:US','SOS:US','SQ:US','SQSP:US','STEM:US','SWI:US','TIXT:US','TOST:US','TUFN:US','TUYA:US','VHC:US','VMW:US','WEX:US','YEXT:US','ZUO:US','APCX:US','MDB:US','IIIV:US','AUID:US','INTZ:US','RPAY:US','RDWR:US','LLNW:US','MARK:US','MSFT:US','NTCT:US','CRWD:US','BAND:US','ARQQ:US','EPAY:US','FFIV:US','FIVN:US','MNDT:US','IMXI:US','HCP:US','VERI:US','PRTH:US','SUMO:US','SNCR:US','SNPS:US','VRAR:US','TCX:US','GSKY:US','ARBE:US','UEPS:US','VRNS:US','VRNT:US','VRSN:US','WIX:US','RXT:US','OSPN:US','DLO:US','PAYA:US','CGNT:US','SCWX:US','BL:US','DTSS:US','NVEI:US','ZENV:US','ACIW:US','ADBE:US','AKAM:US','ALLT:US','AVDX:US','BLIN:US','CHKP:US','CSGS:US','CYBR:US','CYRN:US','DOX:US','EEFT:US','REKR:US','CISO:US','ZS:US','PAYO:US','GET:US','EVOP:US','LYLT:US','APPN:US','AFRM:US','DBX:US','HOOD:US','CCSI:US','STER:US','MIME:US','BLZE:US','KNBE:US','TENB:US','KLTR:US','BASE:US','OKTA:US','ALTR:US','RELY:US','NLOK:US','CFLT:US','CETX:US','TAOP:US','QLYS:US','SPLK:US','SFET:US','FTNT:US','STNE:US','NTNX:US','SPSC:US','PANW:US','ALF:US','PAYS:US','GBOX:US']
#tickers = ['ATEN:US','BB:US']

# Selected metrics in the API resp = client.get_available_metrics()
metrics = ['period_end_date','revenue','gross_profit','rnd','operating_income','eps_diluted','shares_diluted','total_opex','total_current_assets','total_assets','accounts_payable','st_debt','total_current_liabilities','lt_debt','total_liabilities','total_equity','total_liabilities_and_equity','book_value','tangible_book_value','cfo_net_income','cf_cfo','cf_cfi','cf_cff','fcf','roa','roe','roic','roce','rotce','gross_margin','operating_margin','net_income_margin','fcf_margin','assets_to_equity','equity_to_assets','debt_to_equity','debt_to_assets','book_value_per_share','tangible_book_per_share','revenue_per_share','operating_income_per_share','fcf_per_share','revenue_growth','operating_income_growth','net_income_growth','eps_diluted_growth','shares_diluted_growth','total_assets_growth','total_equity_growth','fcf_growth','market_cap','period_end_price','price_to_fcf','price_to_earnings','price_to_book','price_to_tangible_book','price_to_sales','intangible_assets','goodwill','shares_eop','dividends','income_allocated_to_minority_interest','cash_and_equiv','noncurrent_capital_leases','minority_interest_liability']



#tickers = ['ADCT:US']
df = pd.DataFrame(client.get_data_batch(companies=tickers, metrics=metrics, period='FQ90:FQ'))

#if not df.shape[1]:
#   print('Empty dataframe')
#return

while True:
    try:
        ex = df.explode(list(metrics))
        engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:9999@localhost:9999/schema')
         # exit the loop since the operation succeeded
        ex.to_sql('TECHNOLOGY_SOFTWARE_INFRASTRUCTURE', engine, schema='COLLECT') 
        break
    except KeyError as e:
            key = e.args[0]  

            if key in metrics:
                print(f'bad metric {key}')
                metrics.remove(key)
            elif key in tickers:
                print(f'bad ticker {key}')
                tickers.removr(key)
            else:
                print(f'{key} is neither a metric nor a ticket')
print(ex)
      
print(df.keys())
```

March 20th message

```
ECT...
bad metric income_allocated_to_minority_interest
bad metric cash_and_equiv
bad metric noncurrent_capital_leases
bad metric minority_interest_liability
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kevin/Dropbox/My Mac (Kevin’s MacBook Pro)/Documents/GitHub/python3/deleteme.py", line 35, in <module>
    ex = df.explode(list(metrics))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 8239, in explode
    raise ValueError("column must be nonempty")
ValueError: column must be nonempty
[Finished in 10.6s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['python3', '-u', '/Users/kevin/Dropbox/My Mac (Kevin’s MacBook Pro)/Documents/GitHub/python3/deleteme.py']]
[dir: /Users/kevin/Dropbox/My Mac (Kevin’s MacBook Pro)/Documents/GitHub/python3]
[path: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

1. The tickets are not the problem, at least not from the error, as it says: `KeyError: **'period_end_date'**` and **period_end_date** is a metric. My guess is that you do not have that column in your dataframe at all. Because from the documentation of **explode** define [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html?highlight=explode) it should work with **None**
2. You can get the name of the failing metric as such, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23139024/which-key-failed-in-python-keyerror):

```
try:
    # code here
except KeyError as e:    
    failing_metric = e.args[0]
```

3. A workaround would be to get your dataframe and retry the operation until it succeeds:

```
#tickers = ['ADCT:US']
df = pd.DataFrame(client.get_data_batch(companies=tickers, metrics=metrics, period='FQ1:FQ'))

# We can't do anything with no data, so we return from the function
if not df.shape[1]:
    print('Empty dataframe')
    return

while True:
    try:
        ex = df.explode(list(metrics))
        engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:9999@localhost:9999/xx')

        # exit the loop since the operation succeeded
        ex.to_sql('TECHNOLOGY_SOFTWARE_INFRASTRUCTURE', engine, schema='COLLECT') 
        break
    except KeyError as e:
        key = e.args[0]
        
       if key in metrics:
           print(f'bad metric {key}')
           metrics.remove(key)
       elif key in tickers:
           print(f'bad ticker {key}')
           tickers.removr(key)
       else:
           print(f'{key} is neither a metric nor a ticket')
```

Comment: thanks @alexandruplacinta. I tried your workaround with period='FQ1:FQ' and it worked but it did not with period='FQ90:FQ' (see updated error message above' Can I skip columns that are empty or even better set the date to 99/99/9999? ps. je suis sur Geneve!

Comment: Can you please have a look at the dataframe you get and post the columns please? If not confidential, some parts of dataframe

Comment: I updated the question above and posted all the columns, let me know if that is the info you are looking for, thanks

Comment: I see 2 options: either you metrics are absent (which is hard to happen) or they are named different. Can you print the columns of your dataframe?

Comment: done, see print(df.keys()) , added above

Comment: Can you print them for `FQ90:FQ` as that is the problematic one?

Comment: Unfortunately I am out of requests for the day and will try again in 24 hours. Tomorrow I will do print(df.keys()) using period='FQ9:FQ' and will look for discrepancies in the result sets. If I detect naming convention issues, with the columns, I will add those columns in the dataframe then will cleanup in SQL. Thanks for your help so far

Comment: Not `FQ90:FQ` ? You mentioned this was your problem

Comment: Yes you are correct, `FQ90:FQ`

Comment: Hello, I ran `print(df.keys())` today and got this: `Index([], dtype='object')`.

Comment: So this answers your question and confirms my intuition: the dataframe has no column. So you attempt to explode an empty dataframe which the function does not accept. I have edited my answer from above

Comment: sorry, I messed up your instructions and had commented out the while loop which explains why I got the result mentioned in my previous comment. I updated the code and and my error message from my question(see under **March 20th**), the code runs fine when I have a handful of companies and `'period='FQ1:FQ'` but fails for all companies and `period='FQ90:FQ'`

Comment: Print the columns before **while True** run the code I edited now. If you get empty dataframe, you make something bad.

Comment: Code is failing  due to `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function` If you'd like to connect outside of here I can do a screen share and you can review the code (might be easier for you like that) I appreciate your help and understand that you are probably busy with stuff. I've been stuck on this for 2 weeks and may have to find an alternative solution. Let me know what you think, I am based in Geneva, and I am available via zoom or Apple 'screen sharing'

Comment: I figured out a workaround, not the most efficient but it will work for not ;)